# Choice of simple 3DUnet

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am doing a project for which I need to use a 3DUnet. By 3DUnet I mean a CNN that take  a random input (tensor with shape (X,Y,Z)) and returns a Tensor of shape (X,Y,Z). I've looked for something like that but I couldn't find a straight forward to use.

By straight forward to use I mean a non-trained network such that I have just to write:

```py
input = Tensor(10,64,64)
output = UNet3D(input)
```

to have the ouput.

Is someone aware of the existence of a such network ?

I had looked for a very long time but couldn't find it until now...

Thank you very much